# cassandra pig insertion exception

Tags: hadoop, cassandra, apache-pig

I am using pig CassandraStroage() to insert a big data set into cassandra, after running 4 hours, it crashed with the following exception:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
        at org.apache.cassandra.dht.RandomPartitioner.getToken(RandomPartitioner.java:134)
        at org.apache.cassandra.dht.RandomPartitioner.getToken(RandomPartitioner.java:36)
        at org.apache.cassandra.client.RingCache.getRange(RingCache.java:129)
        at org.apache.cassandra.hadoop.ColumnFamilyRecordWriter.write(ColumnFamilyRecordWriter.java:127)
        at org.apache.cassandra.hadoop.ColumnFamilyRecordWriter.write(ColumnFamilyRecordWriter.java:62)
        at org.apache.cassandra.hadoop.pig.CassandraStorage.putNext(Unknown Source)
        at org.apache.pig.backend.hadoop.executionengine.mapReduceLayer.PigOutputFormat$PigRecordWriter.write(PigOut
putFormat.java:138)
        at org.apache.pig.backend.hadoop.executionengine.mapReduceLayer.PigOutputFormat$PigRecordWriter.write(PigOut
putFormat.java:97)
        at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask$NewDirectOutputCollector.write(MapTask.java:498)
        at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.TaskInputOutputContext.write(TaskInputOutputContext.java:80)
        at org.apache.pig.backend.hadoop.executionengine.mapReduceLayer.PigMapOnly$Map.collect(PigMapOnly.java:48)
        at org.apache.pig.backend.hadoop.executionengine.mapReduceLayer.PigMapBase.runPipeline(PigMapBase.java:239)
        at org.apache.pig.backend.hadoop.executionengine.mapReduceLayer.PigMapBase.map(PigMapBase.java:232)
        at org.apache.pig.backend.hadoop.executionengine.mapReduceLayer.PigMapBase.map(PigMapBase.java:53)
        at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Mapper.run(Mapper.java:144)
        at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask.runNewMapper(MapTask.java:621)
        at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask.run(MapTask.java:305)
        at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.LocalJobRunner$Job.run(LocalJobRunner.java:177)
```

Any idea why this happened?

Comment: Ok, I figured out that this is due to that one entry in my data set has a null key.

Answer (score 0):

Although not the cause of the problem in your case, it's worth noting that this error can occur when trying to insert into a column family where the specified partition key doesn't exist.

In this case, it will throw an exception the first time it hits the reducer class.